# Adding color to a table row as a beamer overlay

Tags: tables, beamer, color

I'm trying to have an overlay that adds a background color to a **row** of a table in beamer.

This post showed me how to do that for column. How about row?

[Adding color to a table column as a beamer overlay](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6246/adding-color-to-a-table-column-as-a-beamer-overlay)

### Update

Thanks to the comment by @AboAmmar, I followed the way described in the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/v7qQFV3pjkw). However, the unintended space appears between the header and the first row when the first row is highlighted. Similarly, the bottom row also suffers from the unintended blank margin.

My code is (Only add caption and top/mid rules):

```
\begin{tabular}{p{.455\linewidth}p{.455\linewidth}}%
\toprule
a & b \\
\midrule
\only<1-2,5>{\\}%
\only<3-4>{\\\rowcolor{cyan!25}}A & B\only<1-2,5>{\\}%
\only<3-4>{\\\rowcolor{cyan!25}}C & D\only<1,5>{\\}%
\only<2-4>{\\\rowcolor{lime!25}}E & F\only<1,5>{\\}%
\only<2-4>{\\\rowcolor{lime!25}}G & H\only<1>\\%
\only<2-4>{\\\rowcolor{lime!25}}\only<5>{\\\rowcolor{red!35}}I & J\only<1-3,5>{\\}%
\only<4-4>{\\\rowcolor{orange!25}}K & L\only<1-2,5>{\\}%
\only<3-4>{\\\rowcolor{cyan!25}}M & N\only<1-3,5>{\\}%
\only<4-4>{\\\rowcolor{orange!25}}O & P\only<1-3>{\\}%
\only<4-4>{\\\rowcolor{orange!25}}\only<5>{\\\rowcolor{red!35}}Q & R\only<1-2,5>{\\}%
\only<3-4>{\\\rowcolor{cyan!25}}S & T%

\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: How about a starter code?

Comment: So, follow the [second answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62856/59109) in your linked question. The solution is in [the link there](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/v7qQFV3pjkw).

Comment: @AboAmmar Thanks,  I've updated questions. I've tried the way you mentioned. I'm still suffering from the unintended margin between the header and the 1st row...

Answer (score 6):

In general it's a bit trickier to colour the row, as `\rowcolor` has to be the first element within the row. So, while `\rowcolor{.}` works, using a selective (or overlay) `\only<..>{\rowcolor{.}}` makes `\only` the first element in the row.

As such, an approach using `\only<..>{\\\rowcolor{.}}` ensures `\rowcolor` is the first entry in the row. You can correct for the mis-aligned (or empty) rows by using `\\[-\normalbaselineskip]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ p{.455\linewidth} p{.455\linewidth} }%
  \toprule
  a & b \\
  \midrule
  \strut\\[-\normalbaselineskip]%
  \only<3-4>{\\[-\normalbaselineskip]\rowcolor{cyan!25}}A & B\only<1-2,5>{\\}%
  \only<3-4>{\\\rowcolor{cyan!25}}C & D\only<1,5>{\\}%
  \only<2-4>{\\\rowcolor{lime!25}}E & F\only<1,5>{\\}%
  \only<2-4>{\\\rowcolor{lime!25}}G & H\only<1>\\%
  \only<2-4>{\\\rowcolor{lime!25}}\only<5>{\\\rowcolor{red!35}}I & J\only<1-3,5>{\\}%
  \only<4-4>{\\\rowcolor{orange!25}}K & L\only<1-2,5>{\\}%
  \only<3-4>{\\\rowcolor{cyan!25}}M & N\only<1-3,5>{\\}%
  \only<4-4>{\\\rowcolor{orange!25}}O & P\only<1-3>{\\}%
  \only<4-4>{\\\rowcolor{orange!25}}\only<5>{\\\rowcolor{red!35}}Q & R\only<1-2,5>{\\}%
  \only<3-4>{\\\rowcolor{cyan!25}}S & T%
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By inspiration from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378511/240347) this command seems to do the trick `\renewcommand<>\rowcolor[1]{\only#2{\\[-\normalbaselineskip]\beameroriginal\rowcolor{#1}}}`. There must be no space between the command and text in cell.